# MySQL Replication Between Three Hosts?

Tags: replication, mysql-5.1

We have a need to move our Moodle server to a different host, and our current host runs a LAMP stack that likely runs on a VM.  It is accessed most of the time.  In the event that the current host lets us take a copy of the VM, we will just take the copy of the vm and reconfigure it for our new host; but if that doesn't work out, then we will need to replicate the database since it doesn't have much downtime when users are not accessing the system.

We did something similar with our exchange server when we cut it from a local exchange server to Office 365; just replicated it until everything was working smoothly and then cut over the DNS records when everything was working correctly.

If we do the replication of the MySQL database, it may require us to replicate the changes between three database servers, since the one it is now hosted on only opens the database port to our local network, and therefore the two sites could not communicate directly; so we'll likely need a third-party to copy them through, probably a MySQL server on the local network.

Does this sound feasible or necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is feasible (you can chain-replicate more than 2 servers), but unnecessary: you can forward access using a VPN or, if you do not want to set that up, with simple [SSH port forwarding](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding).

This applies even if you have a Windows server -you can install OpenSSH or any other SSH software or application that allows you to forward ports. SSH is the standard secure tool on unix.